# Syntax logic between Pandas and numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, syntax, python-module

I have a syntax question between numpy and Pandas, and probably more Python modules. To be effective in numpy can do this :

```
b = np.ones((5,5))
b[1:-1, 1:-1] = 0
print(b)
```

But, when i want to do something on a Dataframe with Pandas i have use a variable else it doesn't work, like this :

```
df2 = pd.concat(out, ignore_index=True, axis=1)
df2 = df2.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Expect df.to_csv for example. I don't understand why Python's modules doesn't use similar syntax. Am i missing something ?

Comment: you are comparing different operations. the pandas operations you are referring to make things explicit; the first operation in numpy is indexing, which makes sense. If you want to do a comparison, look for similar processes to compare

Comment: You are right, i understand now a bit better, thanks

Comment: You can use in-place index assignment with lists as well; and `dict`.  But most of the numpy functions and methods do return new arrays.  `np.concatenate([arr1, arr2])`; `arr.reshape(3,4)`.  Changing values of pandas columns is in-place, as is adding a column, `df['newcol'] = np.arrange(10)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work, it's just not the default for pandas. You have to do it like this:

```py
df2.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

Probably this is not the default because it wouldn't nesting operations like this:

```py
df2 = pd.concat(out, ignore_index=True, axis=1).fillna(method='ffill').replace(...).apply(...)
```

Pandas actually uses numpy arrays. you can access them like this

```py
df.values
```

or this

```
df["column"].values
```

Comment: Does the "inplace=True" who make it work ? I did not know Pandas use numpy arrays before, thanks !

Comment: Yes it works with inplace=True, just dont do `df2 = df2.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)`, because the function will return None. Also if this answered your question you can click the checkmark to accept this answer